# How do I upgrade Apache Tomcat from 6.0.20 to 6.0.24?

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat

Our security team has scanned our production server and identified vulnerabilities with Apache Tomcat server v 6.0.20.

They have recommended that Apache be upgraded to 6.0.24. Reading through the forums, I believe this is the process to do so

1. Take a backup of httpd.conf file
2. Using add remove programs, uninstall version 6.0.20
3. Install 6.0.24

But, I have some questions  depending on a quick test I did to install 6.0.20 and upgrade it to 6.0.24

- Where do I get Tomcat administrator login information?
- Is it enough just to backup the HTTPD.CONF file? I was thinking to back up everything in the Apache folder instead.
- Is it possible not to upgrade 6.0.20 to 6.0.24 by running the MSI installer over the same Apache folder? Is it due to the HTTP/1.1 Connector Port being busy/used that doesn't allow an update of Tomcat on the same port?
- Is a restart of the server required after upgrade?

Last but not the least, I am using [these](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.20/bin/) [executables](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/v6.0.24/bin/) to test the upgrade. 6.0.20 gets installed fine but when I run 6.0.24, it prompts me for the JRE path and directing it to 6.0.20 JVM Path gives me a message that "JVM is not found". The JVM info on the Apache manager is in [this directory](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CJava%5Cjre7%5Cbin%5Cclient%5Cjvm.dll)

What am I missing here?

I need your thoughts and advice to make this as easy as possible since this is a production server.

Comment: 6.0.24 ist horribly outdated.

Comment: You seem to be using "Apache" and "Tomcat" interchangeably, and it's confusing. Do you have both an Apache httpd webserver *and* a Tomcat server, or just Tomcat?

Comment: Sorry - Just Tomcat server.